# Angular website not working on different browsers like Frefox and Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

[image]

When I open the website on safari and Firefox , it shows me an errors Assertion Failed.Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Click on the error to see which lead you to where. No one can help you by just seeing just a picture

Comment: It doesn't lead me anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. It throwing an error beacause I have use the flag-icon-css directive for showing flags.When I have removed this directive its working well.